# How to simplify power series?

Tags: calculus, power-series, differential

My textbook was simplifying a power series. I was able to follow their work until the last line.

Where did the "$-2$" come from?

Why were they able to cancel out one of the $(n+r)'s$, $C_n$'s, and $x^{n+r-1}$'s?

$\underline{\textrm{Image from textbook}}$

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They didn't show some simplification. In the line above the last line, look at the first two terms. You can factor out the entire second term and get:
$$3(n+r-1) + 1$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: We have

$$3(n+r)\cdot (n+r-1)+(n+r)$$

Now we factor out $(n+r)$:

$$(n+r)\cdot (3\cdot (n+r-1)+1)=(n+r)\cdot (3n+3r\underbrace{-3+1}_{-2})=(n+r)\cdot (3n+3r-2)$$